# High power source and low power load (device)

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistors, source

Can we drive low power load on high power source? For example we have source power 12 volt 60 amp and load power 12 volt 5 amp. Do we need resistor between them? If needed, what value will it be and how do I calculate its right value?
 Can we drive load directly on hight power source ?

Comment: What happens if you replace a 100 W light bulb with a 5 W light bulb in the same lamp? How many amps is your supply capable of supplying? How many will be taken by the lamp?

Comment: the correct value of resistor is zero.

Comment: I guess you haven’t learnt the difference between a voltage source and a current sink load yet.